# Finding the source of a CERT_UNTRUSTED error in node on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

We run a node app on heroku. The app makes outgoing https connections to many services, but we can't reproduce our problem with any of these services. We are occasionally (6 times in the last 30 minutes) seeing this error appear and having a hard time tracking it down:

```
  Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED 
    at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1381:32) 
    at SecurePair.emit (events.js:92:17) 
    at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:980:10) 
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:472:13) 
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:341:10) 
    at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:369:25) 
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10) 
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5) 
    at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11) 
    at write (_stream_readable.js:602:24) 
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:611:7) 
    at Socket.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:643:5) 
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17) 
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10) 
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5) 
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9) 
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:128:10) 
    at TCP.onread (net.js:529:21) 
    at TCP.onread (/app/node_modules/newrelic/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:177:31)
```

The only hint about files is the newrelic module at the bottom, which I assume would be in any stacktrace. Does anyone have advice for figuring out where this error is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using node 0.10.34, this could be the issue
https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8894

Recommend using v0.10.33 for now.